# Keeping specific comments with bold weight

Tags: font-lock, comment

I am using a bold typeface, but for comments I am using normal weight.  But I would like that some specific comments to remain displayed with bold weight.  The specific comments are those that start with a double comment symbol with text enclosed within braces.

Thusly, for elisp comments like `;; [Package Information]` will stay bold.

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 160 :weight 'bold)

(defun comment-style ()
  "Set style for comments, a slanted typeface with normal weight."

  (set-face-attribute 'font-lock-comment-face nil
                       :weight 'normal :slant 'italic))
```

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/tarsius/outline-minor-faces.

Comment: What I am doing is different from outlines.

Comment: So what are you doing then? What comes after that `[Package Information]`? Anyway, of course I am just suggesting that you maybe could 'misuse' the tool.

Comment: It is to categorise comments rather than outlines, I will have outlines as well.  But one would not be able to fold these headings like one can do with outlines.

Comment: Ah okay, well then unfortunately I don't know the simple answer...

Comment: I would need to match these headings, to set bold weight on them. Or else be able to set normal weight to the rest.

Comment: The problem is that the 'Syntactic Font Lock' has priority over the search-based font lock. So you could set the face for a line starting for example with `cc` by using `(font-lock-add-keywords 'emacs-lisp-mode '(("^cc.*" . font-lock-warning-face)))`. However, this trick does not work for lines starting with `;;` because of the 'Syntactic Font Lock'.

Comment: Of course, you could study how the [https://github.com/tarsius/outline-minor-faces](https://github.com/tarsius/outline-minor-faces) package achieves it...

Comment: Although it inherits from `outline-mode`.